# generating unique id's instead of using mysql auto_increment for different tables

Tags: php, mysql

So I have at least 10 tables with autoincrement the only unique column is email but don't wanna use them as users might wanna change them later so my question.

How good is a guid function like this to use and forget to generate unique IDs?

```
function guidv4($data = null) {
   
    $data = $data ?? random_bytes(16);
    assert(strlen($data) == 16);

    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);
    
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);

    return vsprintf('%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
```

or should I check database for collision every now and then ?

or should I use MySQL UUID ?

Comment: Never use your own methods to construct such things! Use MySQL UUID.

Comment: @juergend but isnt triggers bad ?

Comment: What's wrong with using the auto-increment IDs you've already got? They're already unique

Comment: @juergend like i used to use triggers with number of clicks but i was advised to use php update table with +1 as triggers might fail in the future .. but that was for only one table .. im gonna use UUID() anyways but i just wanted to use something and forget

Comment: @ADyson but in multiple tables its hard when they interacting with eachother .. each table is a different category between staff, teachers and students so i have to assign each user with a unique id

Comment: You should create a common user table and have extra tables (if not just common fields) for the different types of user. Users are common to the whole system and would give a unique ID from an auto increment.

Comment: *as triggers might fail in the future* ??? who tells this to you? do not consult with this person anymore...

Comment: `each table is a different category between staff, teachers and students` well that sounds like a design flaw then. Those are all types of people. Put them all in one "people" table and have an extra "role" column to tell them apart between each category

Comment: @NigelRen i cannot use one table for all user as each category have columns to limit their usage on the website based on their class level and i dont wanna use triggers on a new table for each user inserted unless you mean i do it in PHP with insert and use last_insert_id ?

Comment: You can create a user record, get the last insert id, then use this to add a record to the specific user type table (as a foreign key) with the additional data.  No triggers are harmed in this solution.

Comment: @akina well he showed me an artical of why mysql trigger might need extra eye to see if they really do work with each transaction.. i also read a lot about this possibility .. anyway im only a couple of year into programming so i might be wrong

Comment: @NigelRen yeah i guess its a better solution you can add the answer .. thanks alot all of you

Comment: *he showed me an artical* The link on it is a secret? provide it if it is available... The only restriction is the fact that the trigger is not fired by cascade operations - but this is well-documented in Reference Manual.

Comment: @Akina if i ever come across the article again ill post it here ..  it was more than a year ago .. and i dont wanna just google and send to you any .. but as i told you im only a couple of years in programming and backend is extra for me so i might be wrong or was naïve with the info i got

Comment: @Akina and if you check my comment to juergend i was going to use UUID and was trying to confirm that its safe to use trigger in this case

Comment: You may use UUID() (and even store its bvinary representation) - but is this reasonable? Common autoincremented column is not worth until you need some global uniqueness for a lot of non-permanently connected systems.

Comment: @Akina and there is a possibilty that i got this from here with a reference

Comment: @Akina so do you suggest the same solution ?

Comment: @ADyson im sorry i didnt reply to your comment earlier i got lost in the comments, the problem with having them all in one table is each table is limited by their class level so i have different UI for each type and if i combined them all it just going to be too much code lines in each Activity and table going to be big to get each role limitation but i guess the solution NigelRen provided is pretty good as using such functions in php is bad for some reason

Comment: @TaaLee yes I would suggest the same thing as Nigel to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could go about this.

The simplest and probably the best way being [the MySQL uuid function](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/).
However, you could also use the last inserted id to generate a UUID, as long as it guarantees an ID that is actually unique, it is however very easy to get this wrong.

Comment: well i didnt get the last part but i guess the solution Nigel provided is the best which is a table for autoincrement with type then use the last insert id to add to user_id if that what you meant edit to accept answer

Answer (score 0):

A data that you create with a unique id in PHP can sometimes give the same output. The solution is in the link below. You can generate unique values.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#120123

Comment: i cannot accept this solution as i wasnt using uniqueid() i was using GUID which is very different and probability of getting the same id is very different ..